# Syntax of Wget for windows

Tags: wget

Does anybody know syntax for wget command in windows. I tried its basic syntax but the problem is  file gets downloaded in the directory on which I have opened command prompt. I want to know whether we can explicitly specify destination in its command.  If possible then let me know that would be much helpful for me.

Comment: This is also related to this thread [WGET: How to specify the location with Wget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078524/wget-how-to-specify-the-location-with-wget?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone reading this wants to save files downloaded to a directory, use "-P".

Example:

```
wget LINKHERE -P %USERPROFILE%/Downloads
```

This saves whatever is served by your link to C:\Users\username\Downloads.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual  -O,  --output-document=FILE    write documents to FILE.

So you must give a file name after a valid directory as such:

```
C:\cronjobs>wget -q -O C:\Users\Public\Documents\tmp1.txt "http://google.com/"
```

note: -q option is to say quiet but -O is to say save file to a given file name and it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Use the `-O` syntax, and the path to use.

I've just tested this with:

```
C:\users\julien>wget google.com -O "C:\here.html"
```

And "here.html" was google's index page on the root of my "C:" drive

Comment: btw, "-O" is the shorthand for the "--output-document" flag

Comment: Thanks for your help I tried it on my machine but it is showing permission denied error. Will you please suggest me how to pass credential through command.

Comment: Are you sure the path you provided is writable by your current user?

Comment: yes, path which I used is writable if I tried C:\users\Mahesh>wget http://anyurl/index.html then it works on my machine but if i tried with -O option then it is giving me error.

Comment: Hi blakBat. it has been resolved now. I just gave directory path for destination rather than absolute path with file name thats why it was showing permission denied I guess.