# Download a file from the internet with php script?

Tags: php, cron, download

Anybody know any php script witch is can download a file from the internet? I will wanna use with cron...

Comment: Why not just use wget or curl from your cron job?  If that's not an option, if [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is supported on your host, you can just use [copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I not use wget, because I don't know how I can do? How I can do it with wget where I can add an direction where will download that file?

Comment: use the -P command, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078524/wget-how-to-specify-the-location-with-wget

Comment: Okay... So command looks like: wget -p /tmp/ http://somesite.com/file.jpg ?

Comment: that's uppercase P, not lowercase, see [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

Comment: Yes, it is uppercase... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, php might be a little overkill. You can just use

```
wget http://somesite.com/file.jpg
```

to grab a file and download it.

If, for some reason, you need to use PHP, you might want to try

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/file.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Both solutions are very useful... With the wget, how I can add (direction) where, or what folder I want to download that file? That file will always rewrite per every downloads? With php how I can do that too?

Comment: so, if you want to save it to a specific directory, add -P, like this:    wget http://somesite.com/file.jpg -P /directoryname/ Also, it won't overwrite the file. The default behavior is to add a number to the end of the filename if a file of that name already exists in that directory.

Comment: As for PHP, what I provided only gets the file data. To save it, [use this](http://us1.php.net/file_put_contents). So to continue the example in my original posts, you would do this: file_put_contents('/directoryname/filename.jpg', $file);

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for to the two responders help! I managed to find a solution to my problem. Yeah, do not need to use any php script to download any files from the internet. Is the best, use wget for that:

wget 'http://www.domain.com/dynamic.php?343d6d5gvfegr' -O /folder1/folder2/file.png