# Download binary pack from public Github repository using Shell Script wget

Tags: shell, github, github-api

I want to download particular release binary pack form public GitHub repository and move that downloaded file to given local directory location  What is the possible way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify the location with wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078524/how-to-specify-the-location-with-wget)

Comment: Thanks. I also wanted to know how to download binary pack. by the way I got the solution.  wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition https://github.com/<user>/<reponame>/releases/download/<releaseTag>/<assetName>